# Format of wsn trace file in mannasim ns-2.35

Tags: ns2

Does anyone know the format of trace file of wsn simulator in mannasim ns-2.35
and how to analyze it. 
where to find the documentation?.
many thanks

Comment: Depends which [simulation-file.tcl] you are using. Examples : mannasim-examples2015.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7S255p3kFXNak52bmYwQnQxYzg/view?usp=sharing ....  NS-2 trace formats : http://www.grc.upv.es/Links/local/griswoldNS-2%20Traces.htm

Comment: thanks you so much. i use manasim-rede-plana. output.tr have that: s -t 5.156182578 -Hs 3 -Hd -2 -Ni 3 -Nx 1.65 -Ny 0.88 -Nz 0.00 -Ne 9.918750 -Nl RTR -Nw --- -Ma 0 -Md 0 -Ms 0 -Mt 0 -Is 3.2020 -Id 1.2020 -It udp -Il 32 -If 0 -Ii 0 -Iv 32 
N -t 5.156698 -n 5 -e 9.931408
can you tell me what type of this format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Trace formats :

Please read all text in http://www.grc.upv.es/Links/local/griswoldNS-2%20Traces.htm

---

---